# Can i know what's wrong with my program it run successfully but the val button 3 is not executing in the Main3Activity learning please assist

Tags: android, kotlin

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

    val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
    val button3= findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)


    button2.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    button3.setOnClickListener {
         val intent = Intent(this, Main3Activity::class.java)
         startActivity(intent)


     }
    }
```

button3.setOnClickListener {
val intent = Intent(this, Main3Activity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)

not executing please assist

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you it seems u have missed closing the curly braket } on button2.setOnClickListener and have put button3.setOnClickListener inside the button2 click listener. just close the bracket after startActivity(intent) in button2 clickListener that should work.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
val button3= findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)


button2.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}


button3.setOnClickListener {
     val intent = Intent(this, Main3Activity::class.java)
     startActivity(intent)
}
```